# Change three or more empty lines into two using bash, sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Lets say that we have string containing words and multiple empty lines. For instance

```
"1\n2\n\n3\n\n\n4\n\n\n\n2\n\n3\n\n\n1\n"
```

I would like to "shrink" three or more empty lines into two using bash, `sed` or `awk` to obtain string

```
"1\n2\n\n3\n\n4\n\n2\n\n3\n\n1\n"
```

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 1 file
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data isn't too voluminous and you have `GNU sed`, use `sed -z` to make it work on a single null-terminated record rather than one `\n`-terminated record per line :

```
sed -z 's/\n\n\n\n*/\n\n/g'
```

Or with extended regexs :

```
sed -zr 's/\n{3,}/\n\n/g'
```

Comment: Yeah, your solution works! I thought that we could do it more general using your idea. What do you think about `sed -z 's/\(\n\)\{3\}\n*/\n\n/g'` ?

Comment: @PowerCwel I'd at least avoid the capturing group, `s/\n\{3\}\n*/\n\n/g` should be equivalent. `'s/\n{3,}/\n\n/g'` is IMO prettier, but it requires the `-r` or `-E` flag.

Comment: I think about situation when you would like to change, for example, ten or more characters into four.

Comment: @PowerCwel I see, then I recommend the extended regex version, but you're bound to write each separate characters in the replacment pattern

Comment: Ok, I will do as you suggest. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If perl is acceptable,

```
perl -00 -lpe1
```

ought to do it. It reads and outputs whole paragraphs, which has the side effect of normalizing 2+ newlines to just `\n\n`.

Comment: Unfortunately perl is not acceptable, but thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @PowerCwel Check out karakfa's answer, it's basically the same thing but in awk.

Comment: I've checked it.  Thanks you both.